# Efficiency Problems with Finger Drawing

Tags: objective-c, ios, performance, drawing, fingerprint

I want to develop an app to draw touching the iPhone screen an searching how to do it I have found an example recipe (09-Paint) into the chapter eight of the Erica Sadun iPhone Developers Cookbook [3.0 Code Samples](http://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-). In the example, as you could see under this lines, the touches over the screen are stored into an `NSMutableArray` to later be drawn using the `UIView` method `drawRect`.

With this solution I have a problem when the `points` array keeps an important number of points. How can I solve this problem? How can I call the `drawRect` method without clearing the `UIView` and just adding the last line (between the already painted line and the last point of the `points` array)?

```
// Start new array
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
    self.points = [NSMutableArray array];
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    [self.points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:pt]];
}

// Add each point to array
- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    [self.points addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:pt]];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

// Draw all points
- (void) drawRect: (CGRect) rect
{
    if (!self.points) return;
    if (self.points.count < 2) return;

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [current set];
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 4.0f);

    for (int i = 0; i < (self.points.count - 1); i++)
    {
        CGPoint pt1 = POINT(i);
        CGPoint pt2 = POINT(i+1);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, pt1.x, pt1.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, pt2.x, pt2.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }
}
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now it works right. SkylarEC has a great tutorial [here](http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=132024), where he explains how to solve this problem. Thanks for reading.